# Grep with "half"-exact match

Tags: bash, sed, grep

I try to use grep to match a case like this:

I have a list of hostname and ips in this format:

```
238-456 192.168.1.1
ak238-456 192.168.1.2
238-456a 192.168.1.3
458-862 192.168.1.4
```

Now i try to grep "238-456" but of course this returns:

```
238-456 192.168.1.1
```

and...

```
ak238-456 192.168.1.2
```

and...

```
238-456a 192.168.1.1
```

but i only need the line with exactly 238-456. In this case i can't use -x because then of course it returns no results.

Is there a simply way to solve this?

The given answers with "^" solve the first problem. But not the one with the "a" at the end. Can somenone also help with this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this specific example you could search for `^238-456`, which only matches when the desired text occurs at the start of the line. For a more general solution, learn about regular expressions (of which this is an example).

edit:

For your new problem, you could simply include a space manually by searching for `"^238-456 "`. There are also some regexp character classes for spaces. `"^238-456\>"` should work here. The `\>` indicates a word boundary, and you probably do need to include the quotes. The other word boundary is `\<`, so you could change the whole thing to `"\<238-456\>"` and this would remove the dependency on it being at the start of the line.

Comment: thanks. works like a charm. but now i found entrys with a "a" at the end. is there also a solution for this?

i edited my question.

Answer (score 2):

use awk

```
awk '$1=="238-456"' file
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions:

```
egrep "^238-456"
```

should do, asking to check from the beginning of the line.

An example of tutorial for those regular expression can be found [here](http://analyser.oli.tudelft.nl/regex/).